# How to conditionally display an ACF custom textarea contents only to those users chosen from an ACF User field

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, conditional-content

How to conditionally display an ACF custom textarea contents only to those users chosen from an ACF User field.

I have an ACF User field (`allowed_users`)that author's can multiple select when they create a post. I also have an ACF textarea field (`private`) in the author's post (author's only have 1 post). I'm trying to conditionally display the textarea on the front end only for those users the author selected. This is what I have...

```
<?php
$allowed_users = get_field('allowed_users');
$custom_field_value = get_field('private');
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
if (in_array($current_user_id, $allowed_users)) {
    echo $custom_field_value;
} else {
    echo 'You do not have permission to view this content.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite new to this so I might be the wrong person to answer your question but:

```
get_field('allowed_users')
```

Returns an array of user IDs so you can't directly use in_array()

So if you change the if statement to:

```
if (is_array($allowed_users) && in_array($current_user_id, $allowed_users))
```

Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You may first check the return value for your ACF User field (allowed_users), in this case the return value should be set for return User ID only, then your code should works.